# How to know what the change was for each item in "changes" of Dropbox-js pullchanges

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox-js to access existing files contained in Dropbox. I use a separate array which converts the list of files back to the hierarchical structure of folders with sub-folders.

When I pullchanges - how would I be able to know what the change was on each file to know where to add it in / remove it from the hierarchy?

Is it just a case of the following?

1. Check whether path exists: if not --> new file
2. was_removed == true --> delete file
3. Check whether path exists, if exists & name not the same --> file was renamed

Does this count for the copy, move methods etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got it almost right.

If `was_removed` is false, then the file or folder at the given path is either new or was modified.

If `was_removed` is true, then the file or folder at the given path was deleted.

There's no way to detect a move or a copy. (A copy will just look like a new file, and a move/rename will look like a delete and a new file.)